# How can I return True if the string is find in another string with '*' symbol?

Tags: python, string, find

I'm setting up a script and I need to return a bool when a string is detected in another string.

I've tried to use the function `str.find()` but it doesn't fit with what I want to obtain.

```py
str1 = 'test*'
str2 = 'test12345'
```

How can I return a bool if `'test'` is in `str2` by taking in consideration that '*' is everything after the string `'test'`.

I've tried to use `.find()` as:

```py
str2.find(str1.replace('*','')
```

I'm trying to search a easier way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

**Duplicated?**

The question has been marked as duplicated but the topic linked doesn't give an answer with a string containing a * symbol.

Comment: your replace idea is good. the only thing you're missing is the `in` operator. just check `str1.replace('*', '') in str2`

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Indeed, this function can be really useful in my case. But here, my str2 doesn't start with str1.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh great, is this function still works if there is not `'*'` symbol in my string? For example, if `str1 = str2`, `str1.replace('*', '') in str2` will return `True`?

Comment: mhm, why don't you find out? (the answer is yes though)

Comment: Does a way exists to re library here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, with the help of few users, the answer of my question is:

```
str1 = 'test*'
str2 = 'test12345'

str.startswith(str1.replace('*',''))
```

It will return `True` if `str2` begins by str1 without the `*` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are only planning on using one search string yes the suggested answers will work but if you format could expand to `"test\*hat\*jack"` then you should split the string then insure that all parts of the split string are in the master string.

Example:

```
keywords = "test\*hat\*jack"
masterStr = "I put my hat on jack as a test"

flag = True


for entry in keywords.split("*"):
    if entry not in masterStr:
        flag = False

return flag
```

Ideally your search keywords should be stored in a list rather than a deliminated string.

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "test *"
str2 = "test11234"

strls1 = str1.split(" ") #convert the string to a list
strls2 = str2.split(" ")

def check(str1, str2):
for x in str1:
  for y in str2:
     if x == y:
        return True

check(strls1, strls2)
```

Should work if the rest of string 1 is separated by spaces, its a bit crude though.

[Here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-convert-string-list/amp/) is a page that shows how to use string.split